# Data on corruption in Venezuela

Tags: macroeconomics, data-request

I'm trying to find some data on the level of corruption in Venezuela, since Chavez came to power, and its evolution along time. I've searched the world bank, but they don't seem to have this data on Venezuela...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Corruption Perceptions Index of Transparency International](https://www.transparency.org/research/cpi/) could work for you. Chavez was in power from [14 April 2002 – 5 March 2013](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugo_Ch%C3%A1vez) and the index is available from 1995-2015 and includes Venezuela. In addition to the cross-country data, there is a more detailed [Venezuela page produced by Transparency International](https://www.transparency.org/country/#VEN_DataResearch_SurveysIndices).

Comment: Bkay thanks for your reply. I also found this index, but they don't seem to have data for several periods like a time-series...

Comment: The data is annual. Are they missing data for for Venezuela in particular in some years?

Comment: I only see for 2015. Where are the other years?

Comment: That first link, https://www.transparency.org/research/cpi/, has all the years on the left hand side. You'll have to manually gather the Venezuela data from each year.

Comment: This is a really old post but I think TI warns against CPI as a time series, at least before 2011 I think. The 2011 and 2012 documentations discuss this I believe.